# SMS encryption code

Tags: java, android

I have a project on SMS encryption. It will be able to send encrypted SMS.

I don't know where to start. I work with android studio. Please help me out with solutions.

Answer (score -1):

for encryption you have to use `cryptography algorithms` like ECC, RC4, RC6, ESA, AES etc. and for simple solution you can use Base 64 encoding and decoding. first you have to encrypt data then send SMS, ans at another side you have to receive the message and decrypt the message using same algorithm then you get your actual message.

Comment: Just for clarity, never ever ever ever use just encoding (base 64, hexadecimal etc) if you don't want other people to be able to read whatever you are trying to encrypt.

Comment: 1. ECC are not used for encrypting large amounts of data because they are very slow and the data size is limited to less than the key size which is typically 256 to 512 bits. but may be suitable for short SMS messages. 2. RC4 and RC6 are no longer considered secure any are not necessarily fast. 3. AES is the current standard for data encryption, it is fast, encrypts large data. 4. Base64 is not encryption, it is simple an encoding with no security.